# Why is the HTTP header 'content-length' not always set?

Tags: http-headers, websphere

I am requesting files from an IBM HTTP server via a Websphere App Server (7FP19). For most files I get the content-length header but for some, not. I discovered that when I set the last-modified value in the request to '0' then I get the content-length for all files.

This seems a bit wierd to me. Does anyone know why this might be or is it just a coincidence?

Here is some code:

```
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    for (String value : cookies.values()) {
        connection.addRequestProperty("Cookie", value); //$NON-NLS-1$
    }
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT); //$NON-NLS-1$
    //connection.setIfModifiedSince(localLastModified);
    connection.setIfModifiedSince(0);

    OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
    wr.write(post);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();
....
    // set file attributes
    long remoteDate = connection.getLastModified();
    if(rc == 304)
        data.lastModified = localLastModified;
    else
        data.lastModified = remoteDate;
    data.retCode = connection.getResponseCode();
    data.contentType = connection.getContentType();
    data.contentEncoding = connection.getContentEncoding();

    int expectedLength = connection.getContentLength();
    if(expectedLength < 0) {
        log.warn("Expected length: " + expectedLength);
    }
```

**UPDATE**

this was running on Wesphere FP19. I returned to FP15 and the problem was gone. The length is always returned.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just getting HTTP_NOT_MODIFIED/304 back which has no body and no C-L header?  This seems to be working as expected.

Comment: Can you include the full request and response headers?